# Como transformas uma Classe de c++ para c?

Tags: c, c++

Eu estou precisando transformar um código em c++ para o c (sei, retrógrado), já transformei a parte dos protótipos das funções, que seria o arquivo .h. Acontece que em c++, esses prototipos ficam dentro de uma classe, e depois, no arquivo.c ele chama essa classe separada com `::`

Como eu faço isso pra c? Seria um tipo de `Struct`, mas não faço ideia de como prosseguir.

```
    //codigo em c++ :
    class A{
    public:
        A();\\ELE MEIO QUE INICIALIA ALGO AQUI (??)
        void inserir(int);
        void imprime();
        void remover(int);
        bool buscaValor(int);

    private:
        NO *raiz;
        NO *busca(int);
        void insere(NO**, int);
    
};
```

Isto eu transformei:

```
    //criei uma struct, por isso os "tipoNo" 
    //protótipos das funções
        void inserir(int);
        void imprimir();
        void remover(int);
        int busca(int);
        tiponNO *raiz;
        tipoNO *busca(int);
        void inserir(tipoNo **int);
```

Só que no arquivo .cpp:

```
    A::A(){
        raiz = new NO;
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++){raiz->ponteiros[i] = 0;}
        raiz->quantDados = 0;
        raiz->pai = 0;
    }
```

Minha duvida é o que seria esse `A::A`? O que seria isso no C? eu deveria transformar aquele `A();` em `tipoNo A();` e chamar como função?

Comment: Esse estrutura A::A é o construtor da classe em C++. Como em C não há o conceito nativo de classes, também não há construtores. Fazendo um comentário extra sobre seu código, para tornar seu código mais próximo de uma conversão você poderia adicionar ponteiros de função na sua struct para armazenar a referência para as funções.

Comment: @user215609 posso transformar essa classe A em uma struct A e entao inserir ponteiros tipoNo? o raiz e a busca -- exemplo: struct A{ NO *raiz No*busca;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Eu estou precisando transformar um código em c++ para o c (sei, retrógrado), já transformei a parte dos protótipos das funções, que seria o arquivo .h. Acontece que em c++, esses prototipos ficam dentro de uma classe, e depois, no arquivo.c ele chama essa classe separada com ::

O que você tem que fazer é o que você tem que fazer, nem retrógrado nem progressista :)

Apenas a missão do momento

```
 //codigo em c++ :
    class A{
    public:
        A();\\ELE MEIO QUE INICIALIA ALGO AQUI (??)
        void inserir(int);
        void imprime();
        void remover(int);
        bool buscaValor(int);

    private:
        NO *raiz;
        NO *busca(int);
        void insere(NO**, int);
    
};
```

Essa é uma classe simples, não envolve herança, destrutores complicados ou recursos difíceis de portar, exceto pelo lance de private/public que vai sumir. E polimorfismo no caso de `inserir()`.

Em C++ essas funções são chamadas de métodos e são associadas a cada classe, e cada variável da classe é chamada de instância.

Nomenclatura à parte, o que importa entender é que quando você escreve

```
A um_A;
um_A.insere(123);
```

O construtor de `A`, aquela função `A()` é chamada, com os parâmetros que passou, e um novo `A` é retornado, com variáveis e funções. No seu caso o construtor é mínimo, não tem sequer parâmetros, e é único, o que ajuda bem na hora de portar

E depois a função `inserir()` é chamada, com esse `int` como parâmetro. Só que implicitamente essa chamada de `inserir()` é associada aos dados e métodos daquela particular instância de `A` no momento, `um_A`

**E como fica em C?**

Pode apenas replicar esse comportamento. Claro poderia, como sugerido nos comentários, usar ponteiros para as funções dentro da struct, e seria importante se usasse classes virtuais e herança em `A`, só que não usa e acho que seria perda de tempo e excesso de asteriscos: todas as struct vão usar a mesma `inserir()` e o mesmo `A()`. Se não ficou claro escreva de volta.

Então escreva algo como

```
A* init();
```

e passe os parâmetros de acordo. E como é "de acordo"? Leia seu programa

```
A::A(){
        raiz = new NO;
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++){raiz->ponteiros[i] = 0;}
        raiz->quantDados = 0;
        raiz->pai = 0;
    }
```

Simples então:

```
A*    init();
```

E podia ser algo como

```
A* init()
{
        raiz = (NO*) malloc(sizeof(NO));
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++){raiz->ponteiros[i] = 0;}
        raiz->quantDados = 0;
        raiz->pai = NULL;
        return raiz;
}
```

E poderia escrever em C

```
A* um_A = init();
```

#### E `inserir()`?

Em C++ `inserir()` já tem acesso a uma instância de `A`. Em C não, então em C passe uma:

```
int inserir(int valor, A* estrutura);
```

Mas tem outra `inserir()`. Isso se chama polimorfismo. O compilador sabe qual chamar porque os parâmetros são diferentes. Em C apenas escreva duas funções, como `inserir_int()` e `inserir_no()` e estará ok.

#### Poste o programa todo

Ajude os outros a ajudar você: poste algo que se possa compilar. Com os include e as estruturas de dados. É muito chato ter que ficar tentando adivinhar o que tem no programa

Comment: Cara, você foi top! Muito obrigada! Eu já havia feito exatamente isso, trabalhei e sofri bastante com o código mas fico feliz de você ter esclarecido e também de eu ter confirmado que fiz o certo. Muito obrigada pela explicação!! Agora entendo mais ainda o que fiz e é preciso fazer!

Comment: Bom que funcionou afinal!